# Finding linear transformations with basis values

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help "proof-reading" the following exercise and making sure there are no mistakes. Plus, I need help on b)!

---

Consider the vector space $V=\mathbb{R}_3[x]$. Let $f \colon V \to V$ be the endomorphism of $V$ whose matrix relative to the basis $b=)1,1+x,1+x+x^2,1+x+x^2+x^3)$ and $B=(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ is
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

a) Determine $f(x+bx+cx^2+dx^3)$, for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$

b) Determine $f^{-1}(\{x+x^2+x^3\})$

---

So, in a), I wanted to work with the standard basis, so I calculated

$F(1) = -x$

$F(x) = F(1+x) - F(1) = -x^2 + x$

$F(x^2) = F(1+x+x^2) - F(1+x) = -x^3 + x^2$

$F(x^3) = F(1+x+x^2+x^3) - F(1+x+x^2) = x^3$

Then, all I had to do was a linear combination:

$(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3) = r1 + sx + tx^2 + ux^3$

$f(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3) = r f(1) + s f(x) + t f(x^2) + u f(x^3)$

$f(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3) = r(-x) + s(-x^2 + x) + t(-x^3 + x^2) + u(x^3)$

$f(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3) = (-a+b)x + (c-b)x^2 + (d-c)x^3$

I omitted a few steps. So, if everything's correct, this is our linear transformation.

So, my first question is. Considering this linear transformation, if I wanted to represent it as a matrix, would I transpose it or not? Why do we sometimes transpose and sometimes we don't? Do we only transpose when we're dealing with standard basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to do it this way. First, when a basis $b$ of a vector space $V$ is given, a map
$$
C_b\colon V\to\mathbb{R}^n
$$
is defined by sending a vector $v\in V$ to the column formed by the coefficients needed to express $v$ as a linear combination of vectors in $b$. Say $b=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$; then
$$
C_b(v)=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \alpha_2\\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n\end{bmatrix}
\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad
v=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\dots+\alpha_nv_n
$$
When $f\colon V\to W$ is a linear map, $b$ is a basis for $V$ and $B$ is a basis for $W$, then the associated matrix is the *unique* matrix $A$ such that, for all $v\in V$, we have
$$
C_B(f(v))=AC_b(v)\qquad\text{for all $v\in V$}
$$
It turns out that the matrix $A$ can be written by telling what its columns are:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} C_B(f(v_1)) & C_B(f(v_2)) & \dots & C_B(f(v_n))\end{bmatrix}
$$
A particular case is that of the identity map. If, with notation as before, $W=V$ and $f$ is the identity, there is a matrix that I usually name $M_{B\gets b}$ such that
$$
C_B(v)=M_{B\gets b}C_b(v)\qquad\text{for all $v\in V$}
$$
Again,
$$
M_{B\gets b}=\begin{bmatrix} C_B(v_1) & C_B(v_2) & \dots & C_B(v_n)\end{bmatrix}
$$
This matrix is invertible and the “reverse” matrix is
$$
M_{b\gets B}=M_{B\gets b}^{-1}.
$$
Let's look at your case: your matrix $A$ satisfies the identity
$$
C_B(f(v))=AC_b(v)\qquad\text{for all $v\in V$}
$$
and you wish to know the matrix $A'$ such that
$$
C_B(f(v))=A'C_B(v)\qquad\text{for all $v\in V$}.
$$
What you know is that
$$
M_{B\gets b}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(why?). So you have $C_B(v)=M_{B\gets b}C_b(v)$, hence
$$
C_B(f(v))=AC_b(v)=AM_{B\gets b}^{-1}C_B(v)
$$
so that $A'=AM_{B\gets b}^{-1}$, by uniqueness of the associated matrix.

It's a standard computation that
$$
M_{B\gets b}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and so
$$
A'=AM_{B\gets b}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is nothing else than saying
$$
f(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)=
(-a+b)x+(-b+c)x^2+(-c+d)x^3
$$
because
$$
C_B(f(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3))=A'\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\-a+b\\-b+c\\-c+d\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, finding all vectors $v$ such that $f(v)=x+x^2+x^3$ means solving the linear system
$$
A'z=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
You'll find the coordinates $z=C_b(v)$, but knowing the coordinates is like knowing the vector:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|c@{}}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|c@{}}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|c@{}}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|c@{}}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1
\end{array}\right]\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|c@{}}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1
\end{array}\right]\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|c@{}}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -3\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1
\end{array}\right]\\
\end{align}
So, if $z=(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$, we have
$$
\begin{cases}
z_1=z_4-3\\
z_2=z_4-2\\
z_3=z_4-1
\end{cases}
$$
and your requested polynomials are of the form
$$
(h-3)+(h-2)x+(h-1)x^2+hx^3
$$
where $h$ is an arbitrary real number.

Note that *no* transposition is necessary at each stage. You just plug in the definitions.

Comment: You're the best. Very clear explanation of the procedure! Understood the process perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Hello again! I'm trying to practice this method by applying it to other exercises I've resolved. However, one is bugging me, since it won't even satisfy the identity CB(f(v)) = ACb(v). Am I doing something wrong or this method doesn't apply to all the matrices?

Comment: @Alexandre The method applies to all linear maps.